# How to add a class to a span element which is part of an existing <li> tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I add a **class** to a **span** element for only these `span`s which are part of `li` tags with `class='error'`
per example, this is the HTML which is generated:

```
<li class="error">
  <!--if list has class error, then add also class error to span which is part of that list tag-->
  <span class="error"></span>
</li>
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
if(status == 'error') {
  data.context.addClass('error'); // adds class error to li tag                 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy using **JQuery**, just select all `li` items that have the class `.error` and then use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find all the `spam` elements inside it, finally add the class `.error` to those:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("li.error").find("span").addClass("error");
});
```

```css
span.error {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="">
    <span>Parent "li" do not have class error</span>
</li>
<li class="error">
    <span>Parent "li" have class error</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve the expected result. Iterate through all li elements with the `error` class and find any spans, then add the class `error` to it.

```
$('li.error').each(function() {
    $(this).find('span').addClass('error');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For a pure vanilla JavaScript solution, you can use an attribute selector to find all your `li` elements that have a class called `error`. Once you have that list of `li` elements, just loop thru (using `forEach` or a for-loop) and append an a `span` element as a child of the `li`. The span element should also be given a class attribute called "error" via `setAttribute`.

```js
function appendErrorSpan(li) {
  var errorEl = document.createElement('span');
  errorEl.setAttribute('class', 'error');
  errorEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Error span added!'));
  li.appendChild(errorEl);
};

var errorListItems = document.querySelectorAll('li[class="error"]');

errorListItems.forEach(appendErrorSpan);
```

```html
<li class="">
  <span></span>
</li>
<li class="error">
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using loops you can do it like this-

```
    let a=document.querySelectorAll("li.error > span");
    $(a).addClass('error');
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way-

```
$("li.error > span").addClass('error');
```